# What does the "!!" operator mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm reading this [guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) from Google for Android and they have the snippet bellow.

What does the `!!` do in `userDao.save(response.body()!!)`?

```
private fun refreshUser(userId: String) {
   // Runs in a background thread.
   executor.execute {
       // Check if user data was fetched recently.
       val userExists = userDao.hasUser(FRESH_TIMEOUT)
       if (!userExists) {
           // Refreshes the data.
           val response = webservice.getUser(userId).execute()

           // Check for errors here.

           // Updates the database. The LiveData object automatically
           // refreshes, so we don't need to do anything else here.
           userDao.save(response.body()!!)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is used to convert an expression to non-null and throw a `KotlinNullPointerException` if the result is null. So in this usage, it will only save the response's body was not null, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) for more information.